# How to apply a function to multiple columns to create multiple columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function on multiple columns and in turn create multiple columns to count the length of each entry.

Basically I have 5 columns with indexes 5,7,9,13 and 15 and each entry in those columns is a string of the form `'WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)'` and in my function I try to strip the wrappedArray part and split the two values and count the `(length - 1)` using the following;

```
def updates(row,num_col):
    strp = row[num_col.strip('WrappedAway')
    lis  = list(strp.split(','))
    return len(lis) - 1
```

where num_col is the index of the column and cal take the value 5,7,9,13,15.
I have done this but only for 1 column:

```
fn = lambda row: updates(row,5)
col = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
df = df.assign(**{'count1':col.values})
```

I basically want to apply this function to ALL the columns (not just 5 as above) with the indexes mentioned and then create a separate column associated with columns 5,7,9,13 and 15 all in short code instead of doing that separately for each value.

I hope I made sense.

Comment: Could you create an example of your input data with desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to finding the amount of elements in the list, looks like you could simply use `str.count()` to find the amount of `','` in the strings. And in order to apply a defined function to a set of columns you could do something like:

```
cols = [5,7,9,13,15]

for col in cols:
    col_counts = {'{}_count'.format(col): df.iloc[:,col].apply(lambda x: x.count(','))}
    df = df.assign(**col_counts)
```

Alternatively you can also use`strip('WrappedAway').split(',')` as you where using:

```
def count_elements(x):
    return len(x.strip('WrappedAway').split(',')) - 1

for col in cols:
    col_counts = {'{}_count'.format(col): 
                   df.iloc[:,col].apply(count_elements)}
    df = df.assign(**col_counts)
```

So for example with the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12, |2008-10-11)', 'WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)'],
               'B': ['WrappedArray(|2008-11-12,|2008-11-12)', 'WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)'],
               'C': ['WrappedArray(|2008-11-12|2008-11-12)', 'WrappedArray(|2008-11-12|2008-11-12)']})
```

Redefining the set of columns on which we want to count the amount of elements:

```
for col in [0,1,2]:
    col_counts = {'{}_count'.format(col): 
                  df.iloc[:,col].apply(count_elements)}
    df = df.assign(**col_counts)
```

Would yield:

```
 A  \
0  WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12, |2008-1...   
1             WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)   

                                    B  \
0   WrappedArray(|2008-11-12,|2008-11-12)   
1  WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)   

                                  C         0_count  1_count  2_count  
0  WrappedArray(|2008-11-12|2008-11-12)        2        1        0  
1  WrappedArray(|2008-11-12|2008-11-12)        1        1        0
```

Comment: yay that worked! But I had to take the + 1 out because it gave me wrong numbers and taking it out gave me exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain the line that defines col_counts a little bit more?

Comment: `'{}_count'.format(col)` is a string formatter, very useful when it comes to modifying strings in a for loop. And with `df.iloc[:,col].apply(lambda x: x.count(','))` you are applying the count of '`,'`to the columns of interest. Glad it helped :-)

Comment: Btw I added an edit to also do it with `strip('WrappedAway').split(',')`as you were doing

Comment: If you have more questions, find me on twiiter, user name is in my profile. Hope that helped

Comment: ah perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing row-wise and column-wise operations by trying to do both in one function. Choose one or the other. Column-wise operations are usually more efficient and you can utilize Pandas `str` methods.

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12, |2008-10-11)', 'WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)'],
                   'B': ['WrappedArray(|2008-11-12,|2008-11-12)', 'WrappedArray(|2008-11-12|2008-11-12)']})
```

**Logic**

```
# perform operations on strings in a series
def calc_length(series):
    return series.str.strip('WrappedAway').str.split(',').str.len() - 1

# apply to each column and join to original dataframe
df = df.join(df.apply(calc_length).add_suffix('_Length'))
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

                                                   A  \
0  WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12, |2008-1...   
1             WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)   

                                       B  A_Length  B_Length  
0  WrappedArray(|2008-11-12,|2008-11-12)         2         1  
1   WrappedArray(|2008-11-12|2008-11-12)         1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use pandas `str.count()`

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":['WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12)',
            'WrappedArray(|2018-11-12, |2017-11-12, |2018-11-12)'],
    "col2":['WrappedArray(|2008-11-12, |2008-11-12,|2008-11-12,|2008-11-12)',
            'WrappedArray(|2018-11-12, |2017-11-12, |2018-11-12)']})
df["col1"].str.count(',')
```